# When d.va loses her mech, does that mean it will also take a 25% longer time for her to attain her mech?

Tags: overwatch

In the new ptr update the heroes take an additional 25% longer time to attain their ultimate. 
When d.va loses her mech, does that mean it will also take a 25% longer time for her to attain her mech?
This seems kinda counter intuitive to her buffing situation.

Comment: +1 I'm curious also.  A 25% debuff to ultimate time would affect suitless D.Va **significantly** more than any other hero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the ultimate cost for Call Mech was reduced to keep it in line to what it was before the global nerf. [Patch notes here](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20749857162#post-2).

Comment: Global nerf? Please elaborate on this. ultimate cost goes up by 25% and call mech charge rate goes down by 20%?

Comment: @D.Va I linked patch notes in the post.

Comment: @D.Va it's addressed in the question in fact...